# best way to have a common value on all ViewHolders

Tags: android

I have recycler view with correspondent view holders.
These holders have an onclick that makes them show extra info.

Now if you click on another holder, the previous one should hide extra data.

I am managing this with a static reference to the hideable text view of the previously clicked holder, but I fear this may not be the best way to do it.

Also on my fragment's onDestroyView I call a method to clean this static value as I fear memory leaks.

I want to hear some opinions and sugestions on how correct this approach is and if there is a better alternative.

Comment: just create you onclick method inside the get view in the adapter, this way, each object in your adapter will have a distinct click event. You don't need to hide the previous information, just replace the content of the view with the new info.

Comment: sorry for not explaining so well. The info to hide is inside each view holder.

Comment: i see your problem now, you need to change the behavior of other item in the list. You are storing the info of what item is selected ?

Comment: yes, what I do is I store the TextView which has been made visible. This TextView is one of the components of the view holder.

Comment: and what part is the error ? is it working ? if it's i don't see problem in use this approach

Comment: yes, it is working, I was not sure about correctness, thanks for the second pair of eyes. I can accept an answer from you if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your approach was working i don't see why change it, just make sure that the TextView you are storing in the variable is not null, just for avoid some reference error (what may trow a NullPointerException).

So just do `if(myTextView != null) myTextView..setVisibility(View.GONE);`